# Share async-await coroutine based complex object across multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I know generally, objects should not be shared among multiprocess and the issues that can arise from it. But my requirement is such that it's necessary to do this.

I have a complex object with all the nice coroutines async-await in it.
A function that runs a long-running process on this object in a separate process of its own. Now, I want to run an IPython shell in the main process and operate on this complex object while that long running process is running in another process.

To share this complex object across process, I have tried multiprocessing BaseManager approach that I came across on SO:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers as m


class MyManager(m.BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('complex_asynio_based_class', complex_asynio_based_class)
manager = MyManager()
manager.start()
c = manager.complex_asynio_based_class()

process = multiprocessing.Process(
     target=long_running_process,
     args=(c,),
)
```

but this gives error:

```
Unserializable message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 283, in serve_client
    send(msg)
  File "/usr/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle coroutine objects
```

It's not working as there are coroutines in the object. I am not able to think of a better solution to get it to work and I am stuck on it.

If it was not Python I would have spawned a thread for long running process and still be able to operate on it.

If I am not wrong, this should be a common pattern for multiprocess applications to run a background process and the main process that just do some read-only operation on it, like in my case, and not modify it. I want to know how it is done generally?

**How complex objects that can't be picked are shared across multiprocess?**

Comment: Did I ask something wrong? Downvoters I would request to also leave a comment that what's wrong.

Comment: You cannot share _coroutines_, because there is only one event loop, and it is in the process that owns the objects. What you can do is create a synchronous facade over your async class with methods such as "start doing this and return a token", and "check whether operation represented by token <x> is done", etc. These operations you can call from other processes without any issues. Bridging async operations so that they are async in *all* processes (each with its own event loop) is a challenge, but it may also be possible if you provide a minimal example of your class.

Comment: *If it was not Python I would have spawned a thread for long running process and still be able to operate on it.* Why *don't* you spawn a thread? How is it that threading is not acceptable for your use case (presumably due to the GIL), but the explcitly single-threaded asyncio satisfies it?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. Yes, it makes sense to not share coroutines across the process. *Why don't you spawn a thread?*
My requirement is such that there are multiple components in the project and each part works in their process and other processes mostly just read it.

Comment: That's clear, but the same to apply to languages other than Python.

Comment: I've now posted an answer outlining an approach for proxying coroutines that should work *in principle*. I'll try it out when I have more time and expand the answer accordingly.

Comment: Deleted the answer because, after quite some experimentation, I couldn't get the outlined approach to work.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think it was helpful, though I was not able to get it to work. Was your answer *incorrect* in the sense that it is not possible to work with coroutines with multiprocess?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not yet sure. The answer strongly implies that the approach should work and be straightforward to implement. Yesterday I spent several *hours* trying to get it to work (and resolving a number of non-trivial issues along the way) before giving up. Today I finally got [something that works](https://pastebin.com/0qaVsfks) (with limitations, e.g. coroutines don't return values), but I wouldn't recommend it, except as a learning excercise. If you want I'll restore the answer with new code, but with a warning that implementing the approach for a non-trivial class is **not** easy.

Comment: I've now restored the answer, updated with a newer version of the working code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running coroutines cannot be automatically shared among processes because a coroutine runs inside a particular event loop in the process that owns the async class. The coroutine has state that cannot be pickled and even if it could, it wouldn't make sense outside the context of its event loop.

What you can do is create a callback-based adapter for your async class, with each coroutine method being represented by a callback-based method with the semantics of "start doing X and call this function when done". Provided the callback is multiprocessing-aware, these operations can be called from other processes. You could then start an event loop in *each* process and create a coroutine facade over the proxied callback-based calls.

For example, consider a trivial async class:

```
class Async:
    async def repeat(self, n, s):
        for i in range(n):
            print(s, i, os.getpid())
            await asyncio.sleep(.2)
        return s
```

A callback-based adapter can use the public `asyncio` API to convert the `repeat` coroutine into a classic asynchronous function in the JavaScript "callback hell" style:

```
class CallbackAdapter:
    def repeat_start(self, n, s, on_success):
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            self._async.repeat(n, s), self._loop)
        # Once the coroutine is done, notify the caller.
        fut.add_done_callback(lambda _f: on_success(fut.result()))
```

(The conversion can be automated, the above manually written code just shows the concept.)

`CallbackAdapter` can be registered with multiprocessing, so different processes can start the adapter's method (and hence the original async coroutine) through multiprocessing-provided proxies. This only requires that the callback passed as `on_success` be multiprocessing-friendly.

As a final step, one could go full circle and create an async adapter for the callback-based API (!), start an event loop in the other process as well, and also make use of asyncio and `async def`. This adapter-for-adapter class would sport a fully functional `repeat` coroutine that is effectively proxying the original `Async.repeat` coroutine without ever trying to pickle coroutine state.

Here is a sample implementation of the above approach:

```
import asyncio, multiprocessing.managers, threading, os

class Async:
    # The async class we are bridging.  This class is unaware of multiprocessing
    # or of any of the code that follows.
    async def repeat(self, n, s):
        for i in range(n):
            print(s, i, 'pid', os.getpid())
            await asyncio.sleep(.2)
        return s


def start_asyncio_thread():
    # Since the manager controls the main thread, we have to spin up the event
    # loop in a dedicated thread and use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to
    # submit stuff to the loop.
    setup_done = threading.Event()
    loop = None
    def loop_thread():
        nonlocal loop
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        setup_done.set()
        loop.run_forever()
    threading.Thread(target=loop_thread).start()
    setup_done.wait()
    return loop

class CallbackAdapter:
    _loop = None

    # the callback adapter to the async class, also running in the
    # worker process
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._async = obj
        if CallbackAdapter._loop is None:
            CallbackAdapter._loop = start_asyncio_thread()

    def repeat_start(self, n, s, on_success):
        # Submit a coroutine to the event loop and obtain a Task/Future.  This
        # is normally done with loop.create_task, but repeat_start will be
        # called from the main thread, owned by the multiprocessng manager,
        # while the event loop will run in a separate thread.
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            self._async.repeat(n, s), self._loop)
        # Once the coroutine is done, notify the caller.
        # We could propagate exceptions by accepting an additional on_error
        # callback, and nesting fut.result() in a try/except that decides
        # whether to call on_success or on_error.
        future.add_done_callback(lambda _f: on_success(future.result()))


def remote_event_future(manager):
    # Return a function/future pair that can be used to locally monitor an
    # event in another process.
    #
    # The returned function and future have the following property: when the
    # function is invoked, possibly in another process, the future completes.
    # The function can be passed as a callback argument to a multiprocessing
    # proxy object and therefore invoked by a different process.
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result_pipe = manager.Queue()
    future = loop.create_future()
    def _wait_for_remote():
        result = result_pipe.get()
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, result)
    t = threading.Thread(target=_wait_for_remote)
    t.start()
    return result_pipe.put, future


class AsyncAdapter:
    # The async adapter for a callback-based API, e.g. the CallbackAdapter.
    # Designed to run in a different process and communicate to the callback
    # adapter via a multiprocessing proxy.
    def __init__(self, cb_proxy, manager):
        self._cb = cb_proxy
        self._manager = manager

    async def repeat(self, n, s):
        set_result, future = remote_event_future(self._manager)
        self._cb.repeat_start(n, s, set_result)
        return await future


class CommManager(multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager):
    pass

CommManager.register('Async', Async)
CommManager.register('CallbackAdapter', CallbackAdapter)


def get_manager():
    manager = CommManager()
    manager.start()
    return manager

def other_process(manager, cb_proxy):
    print('other_process (pid %d)' % os.getpid())
    aadapt = AsyncAdapter(cb_proxy, manager)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Create two coroutines printing different messages, and gather their
    # results.
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        aadapt.repeat(3, 'message A'),
        aadapt.repeat(2, 'message B')))
    print('coroutine results (pid %d): %s' % (os.getpid(), results))
    print('other_process (pid %d) done' % os.getpid())

def start_other_process(loop, manager, async_proxy):
    cb_proxy = manager.CallbackAdapter(async_proxy)
    other = multiprocessing.Process(target=other_process,
                                    args=(manager, cb_proxy,))
    other.start()
    return other

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    manager = get_manager()
    async_proxy = manager.Async()
    # Create two external processes that drive coroutines in our event loop.
    # Note that all messages are printed with the same PID.
    start_other_process(loop, manager, async_proxy)
    start_other_process(loop, manager, async_proxy)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code runs correctly on Python 3.5, but fails on 3.6 and 3.7 due to [a bug in multiprocessing](https://bugs.python.org/issue30256).

Comment: There are so many multiprocessing concepts involved here it took me some time as I don't understand it all yet. I tried the approach but with python 3.5 I am getting error: http://mycodebuddy.herokuapp.com/pastepad/bFvt0Zxvo6 I noticed this comes when new process is started as `fork` and with `multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')` I am getting error: http://mycodebuddy.herokuapp.com/pastepad/MtU91UCKlI

Comment: @AmitTripathi I notice that you seem to be starting the code from IPython. Does it work if you save it in a file ending with `.py` and run it with `python x.py`? Also, which OS are you using? (It shouldn't matter, but on my system the event loop uses epoll for polling, whereas yours appears to use kqueue.)

Comment: Running it as a Python file still gives me the same error. I am using MacOs. Just tested it on ubuntu system and it worked fine!

Comment: Can you please explain `remote_event_future` method specifically `result_pipe = manager.Queue()` part. How does it work?

Comment: @AmitTripathi Thanks. I have no idea what could be the difference here - I tried hard to only use the public API. Perhaps it's a multiprocessing bug. It would be useful if it were possible to shave the code down to a bare minimum that still demonstrates the exception, and submit it to bugs.python.org.

Comment: @AmitTripathi The queue is only used one-shot, to transmit a single message that the remote callback has been called. This happens when the original coroutine is finished (and it also serves to transfer the return value, otherwise I would have used `manager.Event()` and `event.set` as the callback.) Once this has occurred, the local future is marked completed, causing the coroutine awaiting it to finish.

Comment: Thanks! this answer my question. I am able to run it. Though understanding all the parts of it will still take me some time. I will mark the answer as accepted and assign bounty in a couple of days(in case I get an answer with some alternative approach). I will also file a bug on bugs.python.org. I wonder would you be able to point me to some good resources to learn more about all this?

Comment: @AmitTripathi If you mean asyncio, I read a bunch of tutorials - e.g. [this one](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6) and [this one](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5557) for the basics, [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/asyncio-for-the-working-python-developer-5c468e6e2e8e) and [this reference](https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/) more in-depth, and [this article](https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) for event loop details.

Comment: Regarding multiprocessing, I've only now taken a better look at it - before encountering your question, I didn't even know about managers. Also, if someone comes up with a better way to bridge asynch functions, they are well deserving of both the reputation and the accepted flag. Thanks for asking an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using multiprocessing module and asyncio module for a litte while.

You don't share objects between processes. You create an object(referent) in one process, return a proxy object and share it with other process. Other process use proxy object to invoke referent's methods.

In your code, the referent is the complex_asynio_based_class instance.

Here is the stupid code you can refer. THe main thread is a single asyncio loop running UDP server and severl other async ops. The long running process simple checks the loop status.

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers as m
import asyncio 
import logging
import time 

logging.basicConfig(filename="main.log", level=logging.DEBUG) 

class MyManager(m.BaseManager):
    pass

class sinkServer(asyncio.Protocol):


    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        logging.info('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))


class complex_asynio_based_class:

    def __init__(self, addr=('127.0.0.1', '8080')):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() 
        listen = self.loop.create_datagram_endpoint(sinkServer, local_addr=addr,
                    reuse_address=True, reuse_port=True)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(listen)
        for name, delay in zip("abcdef", (1,2,3,4,5,6)):
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self.slow_op(name, delay))

    def run(self):
        self.loop.run_forever() 

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.stop() 

    def is_running(self):
        return self.loop.is_running() 

    async def slow_op(self, name, delay):
        logging.info("my name: {}".format(name))
        asyncio.sleep(delay)

def long_running_process(co):
    logging.debug('address: {!r}'.format(co))
    logging.debug("status: {}".format(co.is_running()))
    time.sleep(6)
    logging.debug("status: {}".format(co.is_running()))

MyManager.register('complex_asynio_based_class', complex_asynio_based_class)
manager = MyManager()
manager.start()
c = manager.complex_asynio_based_class()

process = multiprocessing.Process(
     target=long_running_process,
     args=(c,),
)
process.start()

c.run()  #run the loop
```

Comment: Proxying sync methods is clear, but the OP wants to proxy a call to an *async* method, so as to e.g. await `co.slow_op()` from `long_running_process`. That doesn't work because the "result" of an `async def` is a coroutine which `multiprocessing` will try to pickle.

Comment: This is the approach that I was using. It doesn't work with coroutines.

Comment: I see. I read the code provided by @user4815162342. Good one.

Comment: The basic  idea is laid out good in the example.  1. long running process wait on the **shared value** (queue in your exmaple) and set the result to a future. 2. main process set future callback to put result into **shared value**. Wrap step 2 as an **shared** non async callable function by registering it to manager.   The `AsyncAdapter.repeat` laid out these two steps.